# Finding the limit of ${n-1 \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-1-k}$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, graph-theory, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, random-graphs

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) Wikipedia page on random graphs, they compute this limit to be

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n-1}kp^k(1-p)^{n-1-k}=\frac{(np)^ke^{-np}}{k!}$$

with $np$ constant. Any hints on how to get that? Where does the $e$ come from?

**NOTE: Hints rather than complete solutions would be appreciated.**

Comment: Since $np=const.$ there, set $p=t/n$ (with $t$ constant) and use Stirling's approximation for the binomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k$ is held constant and $n\to\infty$, the binomial coefficient is $1+o(1)$ times $n^k/k!$, and the $e$ arises in the usual way from $(1-p)^{1/p}$.

Thinking probabilistically, this can be rephrased in terms of [Poisson approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem).

Comment: Why does $(1-p)^{n-k}$ give rise to $e^{-np}$?

Comment: Wouldn't it give us $e^{-np+kp}$?

Answer (score 2):

Any hint will be an almost complete solution:
$$
=\frac{(1-\frac1n)·…·(1-\frac kn)}{k!}·(np)^k·\left(1-\frac{(np)}{n}\right)^{n-(k+1)}
$$
all factors converge under the assumption that $k$ and $np$ are constant.

Comment: But if we assume $k$ to be a constant, then why do we keep $k!$ in the denominator? As $N$ approaches infinity, wouldn't its contribution be insignificant, being a constant?

Comment: No, since the other factors all have some very finite limits, every constant factor also influences the limit value. Note that also $(np)^k$ is a constant factor.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To keep it a hint fill in the dots: $$(1-p)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}(-p)^k=\ldots\approx\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-np)^k}{k!}$$ and $$\dbinom{n}{k}=\ldots\approx \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

---

You can find more about this under the search: "limit of binomial distribution to Poisson distribution" (Of course $n\to +\infty$ implies that $n-1 \to +\infty$, so I simplified the $n-1$).

Comment: With $t=np=const.$, the limit of $(1-\frac tn)^n\to e^{-t}$ is much more elementary than the decomposition of the binomial into a sum with a growing number of terms. The proof of $\lim_{n\to∞}(1+\frac tn)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}$ without hand-waving shortcuts is rather technical.